# Leaflet: CRS.Simple Transformation for real life measurement

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, scale

I am trying to set-up a CRS.Simple Coordinate Reference System with a custom transformation.
I got a real world construction plan with

- scale of 1:500
- width 11112px
- height 10432px
- density 288

I tiled it using sharp/libvips with a tilesize of 256. I get the folder output with zoom levels 0 to 6 and a density of 96

Here is my approach I tried, somewhat unsucessfully, the measurement is some meters off and I cant figure out which values to change

```
  const heigth = 10432;
  const width = 11112;
  const density = 288;
  const tileSize = 256;
  const scaleFactor = 500;

  const mapMinZoom = 0;
  const mapMaxZoom = 7;
  const mapMaxResolution = 1;
  const mapMinResolution = Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom) * mapMaxResolution;

  const crs = L.CRS.Simple;

  const dpiX = (tileSize / width * Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom)) * density;
  const dpiY = (tileSize / heigth * Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom)) * density;

  const factorX = 1 / (1 / dpiX * 2.54 * scaleFactor / 100);
  const factorY = 1 / (1 / dpiY * 2.54 * scaleFactor / 100);

  // @ts-ignore
  crs.transformation = new L.Transformation(factorX, 0, factorY, 0);
  crs.scale = function (zoom) {
    return Math.pow(2, zoom) / mapMinResolution;
  };
  crs.zoom = function (scale) {
    return Math.log(scale * mapMinResolution) / Math.LN2;
  };

  this.map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs,
  });

  L.tileLayer('http://localhost:3000/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg', {
    tileSize: 256,
    minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
    noWrap: true,
    tms: false
  }).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Ugh, a "1:500" scale is not really useful when all you have is a screen instead of a piece of paper. What's the size of your ideal pixel, 0.26mm, 0.24mm, or something else? Take a couple of control points, measure their distances in both pixels and meters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your reply. I can measure the distance of 2 points I know the real length of (25m) which is 568.1px divided by the dpi (288) I get 1.9725inch converting to cm 5.010 applying the 1:500 scale I get the correct (or almost) value of 25.05m. Now I need to tell leaflet how to scale it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
// dpi = dpi of original image
const factor = 1 / (1 / dpi * 2.54 * scaleFactor / 100);
crs.transformation = new L.Transformation(factor , 0, factor , 0);
```

[image]